# Indexing strategy for finding similar strings

Tags: image, algorithm, indexing, similarity, b-tree

I am working on devising indexing strategy for finding similar hashes. The hashes are generated for images. i.e

```
String A = "00007c3fff1f3b06738f390079c627c3ffe3fb11f0007c00fff07ff03f003000" //Image 1
String B = "6000fc3efb1f1b06638f1b0071c667c7fff3e738d0007c00fff03ff03f803000" //Image 2
```

These two hashes are similar (based on Hamming distance and Levenshtein distance) and hence similar images. I have more than 190 million such hashes. I have to select a suitable indexing data structure where the worst case complexity for finding similar hash is not O(n). Hash data structure won't work because it will search for <, =  and > (or will it?). I can find Hamming distance or other distance to calculate the similarity but in worst case I will end up calculating it 190 million times.

This is my strategy now:

Currently I am working on BTree where I will rank all the keys in a node based on no. of consecutive same characters and traverse the key which is highest ranked and if the child's keys rank is less than other key's rank in parent node, I will start traversing that key in the parent node. If all the rank of parent is same I will do normal BTree traverse (givenkey < nodeKey --> go to Child node of nodeKey..using ASCII comparison) which is where my issue is.

Because it would lead to lot of false negatives in search. As in the worst case I will traverse only one part of tree where potentially similar key can be found in other traversals. Else I have to search entire tree which is again O(n) where I might as well not have tree.

I feel there has to be a better way and right now I am stuck and it would be great to hear any inputs on breaking down the problem. Please share your thoughts.

P.S : and I cannot use any external database.

Comment: So given a string, you want find the closest one to it in a 190M database in terms of Hamming distance?

Comment: Not just a hamming distance,it could be any technique. I want a way to find similar strings without going through all the strings to say which is very similar.

Comment: Any technique i can think of requires checking all the other strings for similarity. But I want to have a technique where if the strings are structured in some way you don't want to go through a path where you very well know the similar string won't be. Because all these hashes are stored in Disk and i can't afford to that may disk reads. I know there are strategies like zipping them and retrieving them (to use most of one disk read) so that comparing all 190 M becomes comparatively faster. But i want to optimize this comparison.

Comment: How do you measure the similarity? From most similar to least similar, is there a threshold for your output?

Comment: Similarity can be measured by Hamming distance or Levenstien Distance between two strings (in my case the threshold is 10-20..the images that i have mentioned earlier has 17) so it no problem ordering top ranked similair images but the real problem is number of times i compute these distances. In worst case, for a given hash/string i will have to compute the distance 190 M times (for 190 M hashes) to find say top 5 similar hashes.

Answer (score 3):

First, this is a very difficult problem. Don't expect neat, tidy answers.

One approximate data structure I have seen is [Spatial Approximation Sample Hierarchy (SASH)](http://research.nii.ac.jp/~meh/sash/sashpage.html).

> A SASH (Spatial Approximation Sample Hierarchy) is a general-purpose data structure for efficiently computing approximate answers for similarity queries. Similarity queries naturally arise in a number of important computing contexts, in particular content-based retrieval on multimedia databases, and nearest-neighbor methods for clustering and classification.

SASH uses only a distance function to build a data structure, so the distance function (and in your case, the image hash function as well) needs to be "good". The basic intuition is roughly that if A ~ B (image A  is close to image B) and B ~ C, then usually A ~ C. The data structure creates links between items that are relatively close, and you prune your search by only looking for things that are closer to your query. Whether this strategy actually works depends on the nature of your data and the distance function.

It has been 10 years or so since I looked at SASH, so there are probably newer developments as well. [Michael Houle's page](http://research.nii.ac.jp/~meh/) seems to indicate he has newer research on something called [Rank Cover Trees](http://www.nii.ac.jp/userimg/openhouse/2012/417.pdf), which seem similar in purpose to SASH. This should at least get you started on research in the area; read some papers and follow the reference trail.

Comment: Thanks the links are really useful. Seems i have more in my hands now.